# Photo gallery with like and share

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I am trying to customize an existing joomla website and I'll be needing the resources below:

1. I want to allow the users to upload the photos from the front-end and after uploading, the user will be able
   to see the other pictures that has been uploaded by the other users (much better if its on a thumbnail view and the pictures can be zoom out)
2. The photos can be like and share via facebook
3. Users can add comments on every pictures

I don't know exactly which components or modules I'll be needing for these requirements in joomla.

Any advice or suggestion will be highly sought.

Comment: i'm sorry..but i don't know what your pointing at..is there something wrong with my question? Well i'm trying to look for some any advice and help here..that's all..now, could you please help me SIR? if not.. thanks for dropping by.

Comment: oh.. i see.. sorry..now i understand. Thanks for the info ^^,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish #1 and #3 with Phoca Gallery.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/3150

There are quite a few Facebook like/share extensions you can choose from based on your needs -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/republish

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir..really appreciate your guide. More power and Godbless.. i was just wondering is there any opensource or free to be downloaded of this "http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/republish"?

Comment: Everything listed in the Joomla Extension Directory is open source and GPL. Most of the social extensions listed at that link are free, the ones that are not are marked as commercial. Good luck!